# ARCHIMESH When adding to object they are so big

Tags: archipack-add-on

I am making a building for my model railroad scale is 1/87

I made the walls and I want to add a door and window

The wall is 11 feet tall which is .0385379 meters in scale
One wall is .05255172 meter long
Other wall is .0385379 meter long

When I Add the Door or windows the object fills the screen and it is hard to scale it down to fit on the wall  is there a way to highlight an area on the wall an place the curser there and then add the image so it would adjust and fit there? I even tried in a new scene and had trouble scaling it down
What is the best approach to do this?

Thanks

Tom

Comment: you could first place the 3d cursor to your place where it should be with shift s -> Cursor to selection (by selecting an object or a vertex) and then you can move your object by shift s -> move to selection. scale down quickly by selecting object, s and then 0.0000001 or similar

Comment: Can not seem to get it to do that.   The 3D cursor I am unable to get it to the point I want.   I am in edit mode trying this   I turned off the 3D cursor and back on  I was able to cut out a square hole now in my wall but I am still not able to add the window  Still searching for an answer